# Mutilple delimiter pandas txt

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to turn a long string in a .txt file into a 2D pandas table

```
[{"CAN":"5420060701","VAL":"0"},{"CAN":"1920010101","VAL":"1"},{"CAN":"1920020101","VAL":"1"},...]
```

Into

```
+----CAN-----+----VAL--+  
+-5420060701-+----0----+  
+-1920010101-+----1----+  
+-1920020101-+----1----+
```

....

I thought about `pd.read_fwf` but my value as different width, (i.e can be 65000 sometimes).
I though about `pd.read_csv(file,  delimiter=',')` but it returns a long row that is hard to reshape.
I have seen from a separate thread I could use `genfromtxt`from numpy but did not get it to run.

Comment: Looks like you have json data...`pd.read_json`

Comment: @Rakesh Wow thanks, works perfectly. I did not even know about json. Should I delete this post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use pandas read_json method:

```
df = pd.read_json('jsn.txt')
print(df.head())
```